# Can I copy a kernel changes to a new machine?

Tags: fedora, kernel, migration

In order to install ORACLE database on Fedora, I had to make A LOT of changes in fedora... How can I copy all those changes and install them on my new fedora installation ?

Or is it even possible to copy the whole partition (OS and software included) and install that partition on a new HDD and launch it ?

Comment: Please describe the changes you made.

Comment: Yes, you can use dd command to copy whole partition.When you didnt upgrade your Fedora OS.Or You install new Fedora and install all packages again.You just followed old Fedora configuration.Actually you can add new harddisk when your old fedora didnt have enough free space.So you can move some data to new harddisk.

Comment: @Liczyrzepa Basically this http://ankrose.blogspot.com/2014/03/step-by-step-installing-oracle-12101-on.html ... It's a lot of kernel parameter change and lots of `yum` or `dnf` installations

Comment: Why don't you just put all of the changes in a script?  Then run it on every machine you need to configure?

Comment: @Dylan because I don't have internet connection on the new machine...hence the script wont help for installing new dependencies

Comment: @JasonKrs well, you can download the dependencies manually and copy them along with the script.

Comment: @Jakuje Cool. Please I'm coming from windows...I don't understand all your repositories....How/where can I download to save them in my windows machine. From there I'll write the script (which I'll launch in Fedora) and bring the saved files (to an explicity folder) on fedora also